# CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation didn't called locationManager: didUpdateLocations:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocationcoordinate2d

I need to use location service in my project, but `locationManager: didupdateLocations:`did called.

> 1.I have already add `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` to info.plist.
>   2.I'm testing on my test iPhone6 device.

here is my code:

```
@interface VCLocationManager ()<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locManager;

@property (nonatomic, copy) VCLocationBlock block;

@end

@implementation VCLocationManager

+ (instancetype)sharedManager {

    static VCLocationManager *_manager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
         _manager = [[VCLocationManager alloc] init];
    });

     return _manager;
}

- (instancetype)init {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        _locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [_locManager setDesiredAccuracy:(kCLLocationAccuracyBest)];
        _locManager.distanceFilter = 100;
        _locManager.delegate = self;

        if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
            NSLog(@"Open location service.");
        } else {

            CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
            if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
                [_locManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            }
        }

        [_locManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coor = locations.lastObject.coordinate;

    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@(coor.latitude)];
    NSString *lon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@(coor.longitude)];

    [VCLocationManager sharedManager].lat = lat;
    [VCLocationManager sharedManager].lon = lon;

    self.block(lat, lon);

    [self.locManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

I set a breakpoint at `[_locManager startUpdatingLocation];`line, but locationManager: didupdataLocations: not be called, I tried to initialize _locManager on main thread but it didn't work either.

Comment: This looks largely correct. What did `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` return? Is it possible that you previously denied authorization during an earlier test? Also, are you sure that this `VCLocationManager` object isn't, itself, falling out of scope (i.e. make sure you definitely used the singleton and didn't accidentally instantiate a stand-alone instance that fell out of scope)? You might want to add `dealloc` method with log/breakpoint, just to make sure.

Comment: @Rob When App asked me for permission I choose yes, as you suggest, I add ``dealloc` method and it not be called till App have crashed.

Comment: @Rob I checked the `[CLlocationManager authorizationStatus]` and it returns `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse` , does it normal?

Comment: @Rob sorry, I have make a mistake, it returns `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse`

Comment: I tried your code, as is, and it works fine on my device. The `block` is called. Are you 100% sure that `didUpdateLocations` wasn't called, or is it possibly that the `block` you supplied didn't do what you wanted it to? For example, I just `[VCLocationManager sharedManager].block = ^(NSString *lat, NSString *lon) { NSLog(@"%@ %@", lat, lon); };` and I saw my log messages.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think this is your issue, but you should recognize that you have a bit of a race condition, that we're starting location services in `init`, which will call `didUpdateLocations`. But there's a risk that you haven't got to the point that sets `block` by that point. I would decouple the starting of location services from `init`. Have a separate `start` method. That way, you can explicitly set the block for the singleton, and only then start location services. That way, there's no risk of `didUpdateLocations` being called before you set `block`.

Comment: @Rob Thanks a lot, I know how to do now